# vdsm service won't start

Tags: linux, rhel, libvirt, rhev

I am currently evaluating Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization and have managed to set up the management server and the bare metal hypervisor. Now I'm trying to add a regular box running RHEL server 6.5 to the data center as a host. The add new host process starts fine and installs all the packages successfully. But after a certain time it fails saying network communication failure. From `/var/log/ovirt-engine/engine.log`  I figured out this was caused by `vdsmd` service not restarting properly on the target. And indeed when I manually try to start the service at the host itself, it fails.

```
# service vdsmd status
VDS daemon is not running, and its watchdog is running
# service vdsmd start
vdsm: already running                                      [  OK  ]
vdsm start                                                 [  OK  ]
# service vdsmd status
VDS daemon is not running, and its watchdog is running
```

The log has the following error:

```
Jul  8 16:34:46  respawn: slave '/usr/share/vdsm/vdsm --pidfile /var/run/vdsm/vdsmd.pid' died too quickly, respawning slave
Jul  8 16:34:47 python: vdsm user could not manage to run sudo operation: (stderr: ['sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo']). Verify sudoer rules configuration
```

I tried commenting out and removing the "Defaults requiretty" line in `/etc/sudoers` file, but I keep getting the same error.

As i'm evaluating RHEV, I am not entitled to Red Hat support and have to fix it myself.

Any ideas on what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Under evaluation, there is no support, but what you describe sounds like a bug. I would ask this question in the RHEV user groups at access.redhat.com, you will probably get response from support and engineering both.